# SQL transpose and concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table having data like:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
b 1
b 2
b 3

CREATE TABLE piv1([name] varchar(5), [no] int);

INSERT INTO piv1
    ([name], [no])
VALUES
    ('a', 1),
    ('a', 2),
    ('a', 3),
    ('a', 4),
    ('b', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('b', 3);

SELECT *
FROM piv1 
            PIVOT (
                   MAX(no)
                   FOR no
                   IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
                   )p
```

But I'm getting output like:

```
1 2 3 4    name
1 2 3 4    a
1 2 3 null b
```

My desired output:

```
a 1,2,3,4
b 1,2,3
```

Comment: But i want to concatenate the values of a and b  in a single field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would seem to want [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select name, string_agg(no, ',') within group (order by no)
from piv1
group by name;
```

Comment: thanks,working as expected and easaily understandable

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat_ws()`. Assuming you will still need to pivot.

```
SELECT name, concat_ws(',', [1],[2],[3],[4]) FROM @piv1 
PIVOT (max(no) for no IN ([1],[2],[3],[4]) )p
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1faae1d37b0379c2f61686351c557cee).

If you are not using **sql server 2017**, you can opt on using `stuff()` function.

```
select
   t1.[name],
   ColB = stuff((select ( ', ' + cast([no] as varchar(30)) )
                      from piv1 t2
                      where t1.[name] = t2.[name]
                      order by [name]
                        for xml path( '' )
                    ), 1, 1, '' )from piv1 t1
group by [name]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server before SQL SERVER 2017, you can use FOR XML PATH for concatenation as given below:

```
SELECT name,STUFF((SELECT ','+ cast([no] as VARCHAR(20)) from #piv1 where name = op.name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as nocat
FROM piv1 as op
GROUP BY name
```

For versions from SQL SERVER 2017, you can refer to @Gordon Linoff solution